# Json parsing problems with node.js

Tags: json, node.js

I am new to programming and I am trying to learn node.js and CoffeeScript. I have read a few books and watched some screencasts. And now I have started to code. Now I faced my first problem and was not able to solve it with Google. Already lost a few hours and I am stuck. Maybe someone can give me a light.
Here is the problem. I have this json file:

```
{
  "title": "title",  
  "pages": [ 
    { "name": "Page1", "url": "#Page1", "class": "class", "template":"templateName" }, 
    { "name": "Page2", "url": "#Page2", "class": "class", "template":"templateName" },
    { "name": "Page3", "url": "#Page3", "class": "class", "template":"templateName" }, 
    { "name": "Page4", "url": "#Page4", "class": "class", "template":"templateName" }, 
    { "name": "Page5", "url": "#Page5", "class": "class", "template":"templateName" } 
  ]
}
```

and the code to get the json file is

```
configFile = require(file.json)
```

If I do

```
console.log(configFile.pages)
```

I can get the correct information.

But if I do

```
console.log(configFile.pages.template[0])
```

I get an undefined error.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
configFile.pages[0].template
```

it's your structure :)

Answer (score 1):

`template` is not an array, `pages is`. So use this:

```
console.log(configFile.pages[0].template);
```